# should this python implementation of strategy pattern use private variable in init method?

Tags: python, decorator, getter, strategy-pattern

I'm learning about the strategy design pattern, as well as the property decorator in Python.  I came across this example:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List


class Context():
    """
    The Context defines the interface of interest to clients.
    """

    def __init__(self, strategy: Strategy) -> None:
        """
        Usually, the Context accepts a strategy through the constructor, but
        also provides a setter to change it at runtime.
        """

        self._strategy = strategy

    @property
    def strategy(self) -> Strategy:
        """
        The Context maintains a reference to one of the Strategy objects. The
        Context does not know the concrete class of a strategy. It should work
        with all strategies via the Strategy interface.
        """

        return self._strategy

    @strategy.setter
    def strategy(self, strategy: Strategy) -> None:
        """
        Usually, the Context allows replacing a Strategy object at runtime.
        """

        self._strategy = strategy

    def do_some_business_logic(self) -> None:
        """
        The Context delegates some work to the Strategy object instead of
        implementing multiple versions of the algorithm on its own.
        """

        # ...

        print("Context: Sorting data using the strategy (not sure how it'll do it)")
        result = self._strategy.do_algorithm(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
        print(",".join(result))

        # ...


class Strategy(ABC):
    """
    The Strategy interface declares operations common to all supported versions
    of some algorithm.

    The Context uses this interface to call the algorithm defined by Concrete
    Strategies.
    """

    @abstractmethod
    def do_algorithm(self, data: List):
        pass


"""
Concrete Strategies implement the algorithm while following the base Strategy
interface. The interface makes them interchangeable in the Context.
"""


class ConcreteStrategyA(Strategy):
    def do_algorithm(self, data: List) -> List:
        return sorted(data)


class ConcreteStrategyB(Strategy):
    def do_algorithm(self, data: List) -> List:
        return reversed(sorted(data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The client code picks a concrete strategy and passes it to the context.
    # The client should be aware of the differences between strategies in order
    # to make the right choice.

    context = Context(ConcreteStrategyA())
    print("Client: Strategy is set to normal sorting.")
    context.do_some_business_logic()
    print()

    print("Client: Strategy is set to reverse sorting.")
    context.strategy = ConcreteStrategyB()
    context.do_some_business_logic()
```

The way I understand the property method/decorator is that `@property` provides an interface for setting the property (temperature) in this case.  Naming the property `_strategy` in the `__init__` method implies it should be a private variable.  Is this wrong or redundant?  I would think that this variable should be named `strategy`, but its interface should be implemented using private variables (i.e. in the getter/setter)

taken from https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/python/example

Edit:

To clarify my reasoning: shouldn't it be possible to change the strategy at runtime like this:

```
a = Context()
a.strategy = somestrategy
```

Comment: Comment specifically says otherwise

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I understand it can be changed at runttime with `_strategy=...`.  My quesiton is, shouldn't the runtime change not assume the user knows it's implemented with a private variable?  What if legacy code is written to use `strategy=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property isn't named `_strategy`, it's named `strategy`, but the internal variable that holds its value is named `_strategy`.

This:

```
    def __init__(self, strategy: Strategy) -> None:
        self._strategy = strategy
```

Allows:

```
c = Context(some_strategy)
```

But naming it `_strategy` causes warnings when you try `c._strategy`.

And this:

```
    @property
    def strategy(self) -> Strategy:
        return self._strategy
```

Then allows:

```
my_strategy = c.strategy
```

The getter returns the value of `self._strategy` when the property is accessed.

And finally this:

```
     @strategy.setter
     def strategy(self, strategy: Strategy) -> None:
        self._strategy = strategy
```

Allows:

```
c.strategy = another_strategy
```

Making `strategy` not just a read-only property but a read/write property.

Note: the code below is not wrong, but it's doing something else:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, strategy: int) -> None:
        self.strategy = strategy

    @property
    def strategy(self) -> int:
        return self._strategy

    @strategy.setter
    def strategy(self, strategy: int) -> None:
        self._strategy = strategy


c = Complex(1)
print(c.strategy)
```

The difference is that now, the constructor (`__init__`) is not setting the hidden attribute directly, but it is itself calling the setter for the property.

If someone now overrides the class, it still uses that, compare:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b: int) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self._b = b

    @property
    def a(self) -> int:
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, a: int) -> None:
        self._a = a

    @property
    def b(self) -> int:
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, b: int) -> None:
        self._b = b


class MySubClass(MyClass):
    @MyClass.a.setter
    def a(self, a: int) -> None:
        self._a = a + 10

    @MyClass.b.setter
    def b(self, b: int) -> None:
        self._b = b + 10


c = MyClass(1, 2)
print(c.a)
print(c.b)

s = MySubClass(1, 2)
print(s.a)
print(s.b)
```

Result:

```
1
2
11
2
```

So, it depends if you want someone that inherits your class to be able to change that behaviour.

Comment: I see, that's clear.  Would the code have the same behavior if the `__init__` method declared strategy as `self.strategy = ...`? (instead of using underscore)

Comment: No, because then there would be a name conflict between the property `strategy` and the attribute `property`. You could just define `self.strategy = ...` and not bother with the property at all - but then you get none of the specific advantages that make properties a good choice in some situations. Hiding how the value is stored can be very useful - if the implementation is changed later, the property getter and setter could be used to still generate a correct `Strategy` object from the new content.

Comment: This article seems to have led me astray https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property
```class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273.15:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        self._temperature = value
```

Comment: What that bit of code is actually doing is calling its own property from inside the constructor and setting the hidden attribute `_strategy` that way - it's not technically wrong (and may in fact be preferable if you want someone to be able to override the setter and have the constructor make use of that override). But it's not the basic case, so it's a bit odd that they introduce it this way.